# How to find most used features in Java EE application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging

What is the most effective way of tracking what features in a Java EE web application are most used?

Basically I am trying to find what features to keep and which features to remove based on usage from end users.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to search Java EE FAQ to get the frequently asked question.
Maybe this blog for example can help http://javaandj2eefaqs.blogspot.co.il/